Geoserver not allowed to edit gpkg
I have set up Geoserver in Tomcat on a Ubuntu Server.
All the geodata is stored in a specific folder: /tomcat9/webapps/geoserver/data/GIS_data
The problem is geoserver does not seem to have rights to edit my geopackages in there. Everytime I try to make a WFS-Transfer or try to edit the attributes within Geoserver I get an [SQLITE_READONLY] error.
If I change permission via SSH like sudo chmod -R 777 Geoserver is able to edit the files. but as soon as I overwrite the file or add a new one the problem occurs again.


don't keep your data in the webapps directory, it is overwritten when you redeploy or update GeoServer,
don't use 777 ever!
Tomcat uses a sandbox so if you don't explicitly add permission to the directory it is read only. look in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tomcat9.service and add ReadWritePaths=/var/opt/geoserver/data (or where ever you have your data directory)


Is there more I have to change? I followed your advice and moved all the data to var/opt/geoserver/... and changed the tomcat9.service file accordingly (added the new path as ReadWritePaths), but Geoserver is still not able to write in the geopackages.

Who owns the data folder and the geopackage

The owner was root. I changed the owner to tomcat and now it's working.
